# bash function to migrate a database - fails silently

Tags: mysql, bash, ssh, mariadb

I have two servers, both with ssh root access via private keys. I'm trying to copy a number of databases (old server is MySQL 5.0.95, new one is MariaDB 5.5.5-10.2.4) and also have the handy tool for later. It seems that I should be able to do it in one command, which I put in my .bashrc on the old server, but I'm having a problem without any feedback of what is wrong.

If I manually create the database on the new server first, this works:

`migratedb() { mysqldump -u root -pmypass $1 | ssh root@123.123.123.123 mysql -u root -pmypass $1; }`

It seems like this should save me that step, but it doesn't do anything that I can see:

`migratedb() { mysqldump -u root -pmypass --add-drop-database --databases $1 | ssh root@123.123.123.123 mysql -u root -pmypass; }`

It clearly has something to do with the function wrapper, because direct on the command line this works:

`mysqldump -u root -pmypass --add-drop-database --databases databasename | ssh root@123.123.123.123 mysql -u root -pmypass`

Does someone see my error?

Comment: You have to enclose your out-shell in back ticks (`) in order to actually execute the procedure at a shell level.  So - migratedb() { `mysqldump -u root -pmypass -- ...;` }.

Comment: I don't exactly know which part of it is the "out-shell", but if I understand correctly where you are suggesting putting the backticks, I get "syntax error: unexpected end of file". I tried a couple other locations for the backticks, but either got the same error or no feedback just like before. And if backticks are required, why did the version that populates an existing database work okay? Anyway, if you make something an answer instead of just a comment, and it works, I'll happily accept and upvote it.